# Proof by Induction: Recursive Sum

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, recursion

We have a sum $S_n$ defined by:
$$S_1 = \frac{1}{1\cdot3}$$
$$S_2 = \frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot5}$$
$$S_3 = \frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot5}+\frac{1}{5\cdot7}$$
$$S_N = \frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot5}+\frac{1}{5\cdot7}+...+\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$$

We have to figure out a formula for such a sum which I guessed to be 
$$S_N = S_{N-1}+\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$$

And then we have to prove the formula is correct by induction. To be honest, I don't even know if my formula is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your formula is correct, but I'm guessing the problem is asking you to find an explicit formula for $S_n$. Your start is correct; now think about what you might be able to prove about the value of $S_n$ by induction. Try calculating the first few values.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$ and we have a bunch of telescopic sums, leading to $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2N+1}\right) = \frac{N}{2N+1}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite each term using the following:

$$\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)} = \frac12 \left(\frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$

Thus

\begin{eqnarray}
S_n
&=& \frac{1}{1\cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 5} + \frac{1}{5\cdot 7} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}\\
&=& \frac12\left(\frac11 - \frac13\right) + \frac12\left(\frac13 - \frac15\right) + \frac12\left(\frac15 - \frac17\right) + \cdots + \frac12\left(\frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right) \\
&=& \frac12\left[1 + \left(- \frac13 + \frac13 \right)+ \left(- \frac15 + \frac15\right)+\left( - \frac17 + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1}\right) - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right]\\
&=& \frac12\left(1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots + 0 + \frac{1}{2n+1}\right)\\
&=& \frac12 - \frac{1}{2(2n+1)}
\end{eqnarray}

As $n \to \infty$, $S_n \to \frac12$.

---

To show the first equality,

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac12 \left(\frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right)
&=&  \frac12 \left(\frac{(2n+1) - (2n-1)}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}\right)\\
&=&  \frac12 \left(\frac{2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}\right) = \frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}
\end{eqnarray}

---

**Edit:** Given the formula $S_n = \frac12 - \frac{1}{2(2n+1)}$, we can prove it using induction as follows:

1. Base case: $n=1$

$$S_1 = \frac12 - \frac{1}{2(2+1)} = \frac12 - \frac16 = \frac13$$

2. Assume the forumla holds up to $S_n$ and prove for $S_{n+1}$:

\begin{eqnarray}
S_{n+1} &=& S_n + \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}\\
 &=&  \frac12 - \frac{1}{2(2n+1)} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}\\
 &=& \frac12 - \frac{2n+3 - 2}{2(2n+1)(2n+3)}\\
 &=& \frac12 - \frac{2n+1}{2(2n+1)(2n+3)}\\
 &=& \frac12 - \frac{1}{2(2n+3)}\\
 &=& \frac12 - \frac{1}{2(2(n+1)+1)}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore the formula holds for all $n \in \Bbb N$ by induction.

Comment: So, this is finding the formula for $S_n$ and you have to prove this using induction, correct?

Comment: Is this the only way to come up with a formula for $S_n$?

Comment: @EtherealMist It's not the only way to come up with it. I actually started writing a longer way, but chose this one instead. You don't really need induction given this process, but if you already knew the formula $S_n = \frac12 - \frac{1}{2(2n+1)}$ you could prove it with induction without deriving it explicitly.

Comment: Ah, there in lies my problem; I am given this recursive relationship and am asked to "guess" a formula and prove it using induction. The way you have shown me is more like the proof itself, no? So, using this method, there would be no reason to use induction, would there?

Comment: @EtherealMist I'll edit in an induction piece shortly...